# Does using string literal in equality test create new strings?

Tags: c#, .net

does the following code create 3 new strings each time the method is called and evaluated to true or is the compile smart enough to compile the right hand side strings into constants?

```
if (somestring == "Test" || someString == "Test1")
{
   ...
   NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
}
```

Comment: `compile the right hand side strings into constants` Well I would hope, seeing as they *are* constants.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are literals, which means that they are loaded with the `ldstr` opcode, i.e.

```
ldstr "Test1"
```

The impact of this is that: anything that goes through `ldstr` is **automatically interned**, so, you can do this:

```
string x = "abc";
string y = "abc";
bool sameInstance = ReferenceEquals(x,y); // true
```

So: yes, the first time that method is used, the literals `"Test"`, `"Test1"` and `"Name"` may be created, but **only once**. After that, the same existing string instances are used. This is guaranteed by [`ldstr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldstr.aspx):

> The Common Language Infrastructure (CLI) guarantees that the result of two ldstr instructions referring to two metadata tokens that have the same sequence of characters return precisely the same string object (a process known as "string interning").

Comment: I never know the mechanism for this, neat.

Answer (score 5):

It will intern the strings.

> The common language runtime conserves string storage by maintaining a
>   table, called the intern pool, that contains a single reference to
>   each unique literal string declared or created programmatically in
>   your program. Consequently, an instance of a literal string with a
>   particular value only exists once in the system

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx

http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/08/understanding-c-stringintern-m.html